# How can i use Function as a property? Setting it`s value from another class and call it in any time?

Tags: c#

I want to create a class with custom callback function.  How can i do that?

How to implement this pseudocode in C#?

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public Function {get;set}
}            


public class SomeClass1
{
    private int  DoInt () { return 1;}
    private void Do    () { }

    public int value {get; set {/*callback function*/someClass.Function();}}
    public SomeClass someClass {get; set;}

    public SomeClass1 ( bool b)
    {
       if (b) someClass  = DoInt else  someClass   = Do;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/900fyy8e.aspx). Just create delegate-field, and Init it in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Func` and/or `Action` types to have functions as variables:

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
     private Action mySavedFunction;

     private int  DoInt () { return 1;}
     private void Do    () { }

     public int value { get; set { mySavedFunction(); } }

     public SomeClass ( bool b)
     {
        if (b)
          mySavedFunction = () => this.DoInt();
        else 
          mySavedFunction = this.Do;
     }      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

But maybe you just want nullable type? Use `int?` as a return type for your function to be able to return both `null` and `int` values.

Comment: I need to set a call back function from one class to another one. For example i have a class with a value. And every time it is changing callback is called. But this call back function i need to set from anoter class. And i need it could be any function.